# Using AngularJs to read IMEI and detect NFC tap

Tags: angularjs, nfc

I just got dumped on, big-time. I have to detect when a 'phone taps on an NFC tag and transmit the NFC tag number and the 'phone's IMEI to a web server.

Functionally, it sounds rather basic, but my only front end experience is some AngularJs (i am mainly an embedded programmer, with quite a bit of back end experience, but just a few small AngularJs projects (and no plain vanilla JS). I did do a few small Android projects a few years back, but have probably forgotten most of it now & am not sure if I can get back to speed in time, so would prefer a browser-based solution.

Which technology should I use here, preferring as much off the shelf building block stuff as I can get. I only have a sweating bullets short amount of time.

Sample code, links to Plunks, demos, even code libraries all gratefully accepted. I am Googling as fast as I can, but would prefer the less error prone startegy of hearing from people who do this sort of thing regularly.

---

[Upadte] The best that I can see is the Phone Gap plugin for NFC (is it also available for COrdova?). But how would I wrap that into an AngularJs app?

Any other possibilities?

Comment: Is this a cordova/ionic/phonegap project? because if it is then you can use this plugin: https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc

Comment: Looks good (+1), but it looks like it needs to be installed. I want to have a browser page which can read the tag, from any phone, with no special installations.

Comment: This can only be done via browser APIs and I think only Mozilla exposes such API. check this out: https://whatwebcando.today/

Comment: Ths is good help and I am looking into it. feel free to expand on it and post an answer.

Comment: I visited https://whatwebcando.today/ with FireFox on my NFC capable Android & it reported that NFC was not available ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did in the end was to encode each tag with a URL on my server which includes the tag's UID as an anchhor parameter in the URL.

E.g. `http:\\localhost\tap.html#tag=<tag number>`where `tap.html` conatins my AngularJs and can get the tag Id from the URL.

A little bit "around the houses", but the only alterntives are to master PhoneGap or code a native Android app.

Comment: In your original question you had _I have to detect when a 'phone taps on an NFC tag and transmit (...) the 'phone's IMEI to a web server._ This solution does not include that part.

Comment: I know. I could not get that to work (without 'phoneGap).  It works for me & award myself the answer to indictae so, but, don't worry, I won't get the bounty points - the system won't allow that. Can you figure out a better way to answer the original question? (+1 for your comment)

Comment: [Update] today, I feel that React Native would be the way to go

Answer (score 3):

Since NFC is essentially using system calls to register events to the driver (like any hardware interaction - much like GPS) it can only be accessed by OS authorized applications.

Most browsers are considered authorized apps, therefore if a browser exposes an API to interact with NFC - you can use it.

As far as I'm concerned only Mozilla exposes such API (sources: [here](https://whatwebcando.today/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/B2G_OS/API/MozNFC))

Your other option is to install a third-party library along with your application that talks directly to the OS itself (In the former solution the browser called the system-calls for you, in this one - the library will) therefore your app will be recognized as NFC compatible and will ask the OS for the right permissions on installation. If you're developing hybrid app I recommend you have a look at [this](https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc).

Comment: Wrt the Mozailla API, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/B2G_OS/API/MozNFC speaks of the FF o/s - I presume this doe snot mean that I can use this in my JS when simply usinmg a FF bowser (?)

Comment: I didn't investigate it any further so maybe you're right.

Comment: Then I will have to look at your PhoneGap suggestion. Also availabel for Cordova, I guess(?).  I can't find an ANgularJs wrapper, though ... :-(

Comment: There is. check out ngCordova and this unofficial wrap for cordova nfc: https://github.com/konstantinkrassmann/ngCordova-nfc

Comment: That night be the answer. I will get coding & get back yo you

Comment: I am not an expert on native app, but an alternative that may be run will be implement a native app (Service) that runs as local web server and read the NFC. Then from the web app sends http polling (GET)  'localhost/tags'